# Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Gestor_Documental\\Modelo\\Usuario.php on line 9,

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, apache, xampp

Aquí se encuentra el código completo, en esta parte realizo la función con jQuery y sweetalert para retornar el envió de los datos al servidor.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Registro de Usuario</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Vista/Imagenes/Astroproyect3.png" type="image/png">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vista/css/Mis_Estilos.css">
     </head>`introducir el código aquí`
    <body>
        <nav class="nav">
            <a class="boton" href="Index.php">Pagina de Inicio</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="div">
            <header>Registro de Usuario</header>
            <form id="Registro" class="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return AgregarUsuarioNuevo()">
                <p>
                    <input placeholder="Nombre" required="required" class="entrada" type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" required="required" class="entrada" type="text" name="Nombre Usuario" id="NombreUsuario" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input placeholder="Correo" required="required" class="entrada" type="email" name="Correo" id="Correo" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input pattern="[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*" title="La contraseña debe empezar con una letra y contener al menos un dígito" placeholder="Contraseña" required="required" class="entrada" type="password" name="Contraseña" id="Contraseña" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="miboton" type="submit" value="Registrarse" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="Libreria/Bootstrap4/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Libreria/Bootstrap4/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function AgregarUsuarioNuevo() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $('#Registro').serialize(),
                    url: "Controlador/Usuario/Registro/AgregarUsuario.php",
                    success:function(respuesta) {
                        respuesta = respuesta.trim();
                        if (respuesta === 1) {
                            $("#Registro")[0].reset();
                            swal(":D","Agregado con Exito","success");
                        } else swal(":(","Fallo al Agregar","Error");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

En este fragmento se realizo el array para las entradas del formulario.

```
<?php
require_once "../../../Modelo/Usuario.php";
if (filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)) {
    $datos = array(
        "Nombre" => ['Nombre'],
        "Nombre_Usuario" => ['Nombre_Usuario'],
        "Email" => ['Correo'],
        "Contraseña" => ['Contraseña']
    ); 
    $usuario = new Usuario();
    echo $usuario->AgregarUsuario($datos);
}
```

En este fragmento de código de la clase usuario, se encuentra el error en la lineá 9
`$exito = $query->execute ();` el cual no me permite insertar los datos en la base del del servidor. Revise varias veces en la carpeta  log del servidor apache en el archivo de bloc de notas de errores y me seguía apareciendo este error.

```
<?php
require_once "Conexion.php";
class Usuario extends Conectar{
    public function AgregarUsuario($datos) {
        $Conexion = Conectar::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (Nombre,Nombre_Usuario,Email,Contraseña) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $query = $Conexion->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ssss',$datos['Nombre'],$datos['Nombre_Usuario'],$datos['Email'],$datos['Contraseña']);
        $exito = $query->execute();
        $query->close();
        return $exito;
    }  
}
```

Y aqui realizo la conexion al servidor

```
<?php
class Conectar {
    public function Conexion() {
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $usuario = "root";
        $password = "Camy20150112";
        $base = "solucion_evidencia_sql_";
        $Conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$password,$base);
        return $Conexion;    
    }
    }
```

Comment: El warning que mencionas en el título de la pregunta no puede referirse a esta línea: `$exito = $query->execute();` en ese contexto. Ese error ocurre cuando se intenta usar un array como si fuese una cadena y no es el caso en esa línea.

Comment: Ademas de lo comentado estás llamando a un método estático que no lo es, `Conectar::Conexion()`. También indicar que enlos nombres de las tablas y sus columnas no deberían tener caracteres especiales ( como la ñ) suele dar problemas y como también la convención es utilizar nombres de tablas y columnas en minúscula.

Comment: No tiene caso usar [`filter_input_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input-array.php) sin proporcionarle datos de validación y, mucho menos, si no asignas el resultado a una variable. Luego, esto: `"Nombre" => ['Nombre'],` es donde inicia el error, porque debería ser `"Nombre" => $_POST['Nombre'],` o `"Nombre" => $resultado_de_filtrado['Nombre'],`

Comment: Realice los cambios y me dio ahora los siguientes errores : `Notice: Undefined index: Nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor_Documental\Controlador\Usuario\Registro\AgregarUsuario.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: Nombre_Usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor_Documental\Controlador\Usuario\Registro\AgregarUsuario.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: Correo in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor_Documental\Controlador\Usuario\Registro\AgregarUsuario.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: Contraseña in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor_Documental\Controlador\Usuario\Registro\AgregarUsuario.php on line 7
 `

Comment: El código quedo de la siguiente manera: ```<?php
require_once "../../../Modelo/Usuario.php";
    $datos = array(
        "nombre" => $_POST['Nombre'],
        "nombre_usuario" => $_POST['Nombre_Usuario'],
        "email" => $_POST['Correo'],
        "contrasena" => $_POST['Contraseña']
    ); 
    $usuario = new Usuario();
    echo AgregarUsuario($datos); ```

Comment: No soy experto pero soy metido jaja, se me ocurre que en el input con "name="Nombre Usuario" te falta el Guión bajo. Si son tonterías no me hagas caso jeje

Answer (score 1):

El echo debería ser

```
 echo AgregarUsuario($datos);
```

En lugar de

```
 echo $usuario->AgregarUsuario($datos);
```

Porque ese query no te devuelve un array

Comment: Realice el cambio en el código y me arrojo el siguiente error:`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function AgregarUsuario() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor_Documental\Controlador\Usuario\Registro\AgregarUsuario.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor_Documental\Controlador\Usuario\Registro\AgregarUsuario.php on line 10`